# MySQL making an index linked field that adjusts based on previous row

Tags: mysql, indexing

Is it possible to create a field whole values automatically populate based on the index field and an adjustment field?

```
| indexfield | adjustment | adjusted field |
|:----1------|:----------:| ------1-------:|
|:----2------|:----3-----:| -----2-------:|
|:----3------|:----------:| -----5-------:|
|:----4------|:----2-----:| -----6-------:|
|:----5------|:----------:| -----8-------:|
```

From what you see above, the row includes a reference which will increase based on the prior row's adjustment value.

Furthermore, if I delete a row, it automatically repopulates based on whether or not the prior row has an adjustment value.

This was something I managed to do with Filemaker Pro version 8, but no longer can do with newer Filemaker Pro, and hoped i could do on a server side with PHPMyAdmin and MySQL

Comment: I'm pretty sure MySQL doesn't have anything like this.

Comment: FYI, PhpMyAdmin is just a web application for querying and managing MySQL databases, it's not the database itself.

Comment: What results do you want from that sample data?

Comment: Is the published data your start point or desired result? If the former what should your desired result look like, if the latter more explanation is required.

Comment: I'm looking to take an existing tab delimited table of the above structure and convert it to a database managed by MySQL within PHPMyAdmin.   I want to be able to insert records in the middle of the table and have everything renumber following the logic above.